# Is DSLAM connected to BRAS through PSTN?

Tags: internet, isp

I am searching for any real world example to understand how the internet traffic reaches the ISP.

I tried to search google for an answer I found that it is connected through ethernet. But I want real world examples.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The connectivity between DSLAM and BRAS could be either by ATM or Ethernet and in case the user should be forwarded to another ISP for the authentication and the connectivity  L2TP tunnel will be established between the BRAS and ISP router called LNS and the user PPP session will be forwarded over the tunnel for AAA and internet service after the session get established

the below link has good information regarding this : 
[Real Life DSL](https://ccieblog.co.uk/dsl/real-life-dsl)